# Redirect folder to subdomain with folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Every image in the folder

```
http://www.example.com/files/thumbs
```

needs a redirect to

```
http://images.example.com/files/thumbs
```

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^files/thumbs(.*)$ http://images.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but result is:

```
http://images.example.com//test.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://images.example.com/files/thumbs/test.jpg
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture full request URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(files/thumbs/.*)$ http://images.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I made a test but when I open http://images.example.com/files/thumbs/test.jpg its saying: to many redirects. I guess there is something wrong. Maybe you know?

Comment: Probably both domains are pointing to same host. See updated answer, you will need `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ...` as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Yes both pointing to the same host. Now images.example.com/files/thumbs/test.jpg is working but now its saying to www.example.com/files/thumbs/test.jpg there are to many redirects. Thank you again for help, if possible?

Comment: sorry, as always, cache issue ;)...works like a charm now. you are the htaccess hero. I see your picture every when there is a htaccess question on stack ;)

Comment: I moved now with the subdomain to a CDN (different host) . Would you please give me the first redirection as a comment again? thank you so much

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still having this problem: "too many redirects". This is my rule I use. Is this correct?
RewriteRule ^(files/thumbs/.*)$ http://images.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]     (images.example.com) is now a CDN CName URL with different IP  thank you again for help

Comment: Not sure, too many redirects mean both domains are probably still on same server. You better keep `RewriteCond` in that case.

Comment: same with rewritecond. image.example.com is 100% setted with cname to a different cdn location. maybe this is the problem? when you have anything that I can try, feel free to offer. thank you very much

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question with more details and you will get better help with all experts on SO.

Comment: done, please read what I wrote in important. Maybe this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287374/301-redirect-all-images-to-cdn